# Create stored procedure from another stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure like:

```
create procedure [dbo].[Mark]
   SELECT 
       NAME, TOT1, TOT2, TOT3, (TOT1+TOT2+TOT3)/3 AS Average
   FROM
       (SELECT  
            NAME, 
            ISNULL([1],0) AS TOT1,
            ISNULL([2],0) AS TOT2,
            ISNULL([3],0) AS TOT3
       FROM 
           (SELECT  
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY NAME) RN,
                NAME,
                TOT
            FROM    
                T) S
 PIVOT (MAX(TOT) FOR RN IN ([1],[2],[3])) AS PVT
 ) T
```

The output of this stored procedure is:

```
name   Tot1  Tot2  Tot3    Avg
-------------------------------
 a      50     30    45     42
 b      30     0      0     10
```

From this stored procedure, I want to create another stored procedure to get record the Average between 20-50. How to get? I try with temp table. But I could not access temp table to another stored procedure

My output must be

```
name   Tot1  Tot2  Tot3    Avg
---------------------------------
 a      50     30    45    42
```

Comment: You want a procedure to compute the average only ? Or to compute everything with the average ?

Comment: What do you mean Average of 10-50 ? Can you show the expected result ?

Comment: sorry i edited my question.. not 10-50.. filter record based on between two numbers. for example between 20 to 50 means , i want get record like ,a ,50, 30,45, 42

Comment: you already done average column, what another you want?

Comment: i want those who are having average between 20 and 50

Comment: @user3172066 so just add this filter to your select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just update your procedure to accept optional parameters:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Mark 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
     @RANGE_START INT = NULL, @RANGE_END INT = NULL
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT *
    FROM (
    SELECT 
           NAME, TOT1, TOT2, TOT3, (TOT1+TOT2+TOT3)/3 AS Average
       FROM
          (SELECT  
                NAME, 
                ISNULL([1],0) AS TOT1,
                ISNULL([2],0) AS TOT2,
                ISNULL([3],0) AS TOT3
           FROM 
               (SELECT  
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY NAME) RN,
                    NAME,
                    TOT
                FROM    
                    T) S
     PIVOT (MAX(TOT) FOR RN IN ([1],[2],[3])) AS PVT
     ) T
     ) R
     WHERE (@RANGE_START IS NULL OR R.Average >= @RANGE_START) 
       AND( @RANGE_END IS NULL OR R.Average <=  @RANGE_END)

END
GO
```

**Usage (New Parameters):**

```
EXEC dbo.Mark 20, 41
```

**Result:**

```
   NAME    TOT1    TOT2    TOT3    Average
    a       50      30      45        41
```

**Usage (Same as before):**

```
EXEC dbo.Mark
```

**Result:**

```
NAME    TOT1    TOT2    TOT3    Average
a       50      30      45        41
b       30      0       0         10
```

### Method 2:

If you really want to create a new procedure and use Temp tables, then:

**Update Initial:**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Mark 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
           NAME, TOT1, TOT2, TOT3, (TOT1+TOT2+TOT3)/3 AS Average INTO ##TEMP
       FROM
          (SELECT  
                NAME, 
                ISNULL([1],0) AS TOT1,
                ISNULL([2],0) AS TOT2,
                ISNULL([3],0) AS TOT3
           FROM 
               (SELECT  
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY NAME) RN,
                    NAME,
                    TOT
                FROM    
                    T) S
     PIVOT (MAX(TOT) FOR RN IN ([1],[2],[3])) AS PVT
     ) T

     SELECT * FROM ##TEMP

END
GO
```

**Create New One:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Mark2
    @RANGE_START INT = NULL, @RANGE_END INT = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    EXEC dbo.Mark

    SELECT * FROM ##TEMP
    WHERE Average BETWEEN @RANGE_START AND @RANGE_END

   DROP TABLE ##TEMP
END
GO
```

**Usage:**

```
EXEC Mark2 20, 50
```

Comment: in my case, i have to create new stored proc. so i follow method 2.. in this Update Initial: is working fine. Then Create New One: in this i could not access Temp table. the error is like invalid object name.

Comment: @user3172066 procedure will generate syntax error, but don't worry if you create it, it will run fine. Just Create it an test it. ##TEMP is not valid inside Mark2, but once you run Mark inside Mark2, the table will be valid. Just try it.

Comment: Hey i try with second method. I could not proceed next by this output. Now i do not want to create new one. so i follow your first method, it  shows error like incorrect syntax near " ) R" . how to fix it.?

Comment: @user3185569-> can u help me that how can i extract this query (method 1) to find max average data between two dates from table?. That is my table contain one column as examdate

Comment: @user3172066 Just after `FROM T` add `where T.examdate BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-07-12' `. These are dummy values, you can replace with parameters.

Comment: yes thankq. I got it. Then one more condition to check..  That i need Exam centerwise(another column name) topper on the basis of Average. I tried .But it shows some error. can u help?

Comment: i try with  T where T.CentreExam='AAA' and T.DateExam BETWEEN '2016-07-15' and '2016-07-28' .It works fine. but need to extend this query to get topper basis of average

Comment: @user3172066 this is turning into a multi-question question. If you really want to learn, you have to take a t-sql tutorial. If i kept just telling you the answer, I'm not going to benefit you. Try to google `t-sql tutorial` and have some time practicing it.

Comment: user3185569->Yes thanq..then please send link of best tutorial.And its urgent work. can u help for this only.?

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @MyTableVar TABLE(
    name VARCHAR(20),
    Tot1 [decimal](15, 6),
    Tot2 [decimal](15, 6),
    Tot3 [decimal](15, 6),
    Avg [decimal](15, 6))

INSERT INTO @MyTableVar EXECUTE sp_executesql [Mark]

SELECT * FROM @MyTableVar WHERE Avg BETWEEN 20 AND 50
```

Just replace the temporary table `@MyTableVar` with the data types that you need. I haven't tested this but I'm pretty sure `sp_executesql` is what your looking for.

**EDIT:**
UPDATE the datatypes for you.

Comment: INSERT INTO @MyTableVar EXECUTE sp_executesql [dbo].[Mark]
 in this line, i have error like incorrect syndex near '.'  (dot)

Comment: Try `INSERT INTO @MyTableVar EXECUTE sp_executesql Mark` instead

Comment: Updated. I believe your code is working now. I would have made a sqlfiddle for this but I'm pretty much sure reading the sql manual would help you understand `sp_executesql` much better.

Comment: please edit ur answer like INSERT INTO @MyTableVar EXECUTE dbo.Mark

Comment: Up to you bro. Cheers !

Comment: I got output by using your code. But i could not bind this in Gridview or any other . And also i could not use this output. Just i can be viewed.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to handle this is to simply not use a stored procedure. If you create a table value function instead, you can then easily write other queries/stored procedures against it.